# Apache2 config for Amazon EC2 c3.2xlarge instance

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2

Currently, I'm using `c3.2xlarge` Amazon EC2 instance (8 vCPU and 15GB of RAM) with Apache2 installed on it. The server is under high load almost every time, so, sometimes it hangs up  and CPU is overloaded for a couple minutes. Health Check reporting that instance is in unhealthy state. However, this is what I see running `htop` while server in a "working day" mode:

[image]

As you can see, the CPU is healthy, but only 2GB of RAM out of 15 is used.

This is `mpm_prefork.conf` file:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        StartServers             20
        MinSpareServers          20
        MaxSpareServers          30
        ServerLimit              360
        MaxClients               360
        MaxRequestWorkers        360
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   1000
</IfModule>
```

And this is part of `apache2.conf`:

```
Timeout 200
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 700
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

I already changed ServerLimit and MaxClients from 150 to 360 and situation seems better (only 1GB of RAM was used before).

How can I optimize performance with prefork/apache config to archive more RAM usage and less CPU throttling?

Answer (score 0):

Fond out the average amount of memory consumed by each Apache process Y (`ps -ef | grep httpd`). Subtract the amount of memory that other processes in your VM are consuming from 15GB (add some more buffer if you anticipate that the other processes may consume more memory in future). Let the difference be X. You can then set the MaxClients as approximately `X/Y`.